# Restrict WSO2 store sign up to create a default application

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

On sign up into WSO2 store, a default app is created for the user. How can we restrict it? Also, can we limit the number of applications, the new users can create in the store? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot restrict the default application and the number of applications that can be created. But if you use a Store custom theme, you can hide the default app in Store if required. https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Customizing+the+API+Store